# Check responsive design using chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have a webpage with svg background and form. The background is divided to 2 sections.

**Top area** - background image / **bottom area** - background color

Had an issue with some mobile devices, the bottom background comes up behind trees like this.

[image]

I have fixed that issue by writing media queries. After that I checked major devices responsive compatibility by chrome device emulator. All are fine. But my client complained me that he was getting that background issue on his device.(microsoft surface pro 4) Then I got back to chrome device emulator and added custom device as a surface pro 4 and set actual resolution.(2736x1824) But it's showing fine on chrome tool. (pc) This is my settings.

[image]

I'm getting this error because of not setting up device pixel ratio? or any other way to check mobile compatibility correctly?

Comment: Chrome does not simulate other rendering engines. So if the customer uses e.g. Edge on the surface, then you need to test your rendering with Edge. It could be an error in your html/css code that is only visible in other browsers then Chrome, or it might be a bug in Edge.

Comment: He is using chrome on his device.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ad-dons available for testing responsive website on respective devices I used following add on you can try this addons

- Responsive Web Design Tester - chrome
- toggle Responsive - Mozilla

Just search for this addons and click on the add addons button on respective browser search for respective addons .